# Azure Devops GIthub webhooks

Tags: github, azure-devops

We had azure pipeline which use to work, but recently the PR trigger are not working.

Hence, I deleted webhooks from github repo. I created new service account and new pipeline with new service account. However, it does not seem to recreate webooks in github.

any thoughts?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 0):

Which model are you using, classic editor build or YAML build?

If you are using YAML build, we could select GitHub as source.

[image]

And we could specify the target branches when validating your pull requests. For example, to validate pull requests that target master and releases/*, you can use the following `pr` trigger.

```
pr:
- master
- releases/*
```

If you are using classic editor build. We could select the Pull request validation trigger and check the Enable pull request validation check box to enable builds on pull requests. Check the pic below.

[image]

We could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#pr-triggers) for more details.